Error con FPDF version 1.86 tipos de operando no admitidos
Revisando encontré que agregando a esta linea de código un 0 se corregía ya que no se estaba declarando el valor de $h pero al agregar el cero se queda colgado el navegador hasta que arroja "Memoria insuficiente" el ejemplo seria así:
**$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , 0, $ext_logo);**

No e logrado encontrar mas información de este tipo de error por lo que agradecería el apoyo, sugerencias de como solucionar o que otro detalle se puede evaluar para dar con el problema

// FUNCION DE LA FACTURA //
function addFact( $nom, $adresse, $logo, $ext_logo  )
{
    $x1 = 30;
    $y1 = 4;
    //Positionnement en bas
    $this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo);
    $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $nom );
    $this->Cell( $length, 2, $nom);
    $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 + 4 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $adresse );
    //Coordonnées de la société
    $lignes = $this->sizeOfText( $adresse, $length) ;
    $this->MultiCell($length, 4, $adresse);
}

// FUNCION IMAGEN EXTRAIDA DE FPDF.PHP //
    function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')
{
    // Put an image on the page
    if($file=='')
        $this->Error('Image file name is empty');
    if(!isset($this->images[$file]))
    {
        // First use of this image, get info
        if($type=='')
        {
            $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
            if(!$pos)
                $this->Error('Image file has no extension and no type was specified: '.$file);
            $type = substr($file,$pos+1);
        }
        $type = strtolower($type);
        if($type=='jpeg')
            $type = 'jpg';
        $mtd = '_parse'.$type;
        if(!method_exists($this,$mtd))
            $this->Error('Unsupported image type: '.$type);
        $info = $this->$mtd($file);
        $info['i'] = count($this->images)+1;
        $this->images[$file] = $info;
    }
    else
        $info = $this->images[$file];

    // Automatic width and height calculation if needed
    if($w==0 && $h==0)
    {
        // Put image at 96 dpi
        $w = -96;
        $h = -96;
    }
    if($w<0)
        $w = -$info['w']*72/$w/$this->k;
    if($h<0)
        $h = -$info['h']*72/$h/$this->k;
    if($w==0)
        $w = $h*$info['w']/$info['h'];
    if($h==0)
        $h = $w*$info['h']/$info['w'];

    // Flowing mode
    if($y===null)
    {
        if($this->y+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger && !$this->InHeader && !$this->InFooter && $this->AcceptPageBreak())
        {
            // Automatic page break
            $x2 = $this->x;
            $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation,$this->CurPageSize,$this->CurRotation);
            $this->x = $x2;
        }
        $y = $this->y;
        $this->y += $h;
    }

    if($x===null)
        $x = $this->x;
    $this->_out(sprintf('q %.2F 0 0 %.2F %.2F %.2F cm /I%d Do Q',$w*$this->k,$h*$this->k,$x*$this->k,($this->h-($y+$h))*$this->k,$info['i']));
    if($link)
        $this->Link($x,$y,$w,$h,$link);

}

Error que me arroja el navegador:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * float in

Dejo solución que encontré probando, por si es de utilidad.
Saludos.
// FUNCION DE LA FACTURA //
$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , 0, $ext_logo);

// FUNCION DE LA FACTURA //
$pdf->addFact(iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $empresa),
          $documento."\n".
          iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', "Direccion: "). iconv('ISO-8859-1',
          'UTF-8', $direccion)."\n".
           iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', "Telefono: ").$telefono."\n".
           "Email: ".$email,$logo,$ext_logo);

De esta manera logré que funcionara. :)
